# square(length, startx, starty)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

In my computer class, I am working on a program that draws 4 shapes as I am not knowledgeable in Python. At the bottom is the code.
I am now supposed to turn part of the code to use
square(length, startx, starty)
The question was

> Improve your functions from exercise #2 by including a parameter so
> you can also specify the starting location of the shape and add it to
> your program when calling your functions.

Does anyone know what I am supposed to do?

```
def square():
    mike.goto(-250, 250)
    mike.pendown()
    mike.forward(length)
    mike.left(90)
    mike.forward(length)
    mike.left(90)
    mike.forward(length)
    mike.left(90)
    mike.forward(length)
    mike.penup()
    mike.forward(length)
    mike.pendown()


square()
```

Comment: It looks like you're supposed to modify the function definition itself.

Comment: `def square():` ⟶ `def square(length, startx, starty):` Then use those values in the function.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to be asking for answers to your homework problems. If you are stuck on something specific we can help but we shouldn't be answering your homework problems verbatim. (I know people will and have because they want the karma but they shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code you attached is a function used to draw a square starting at  `(-250, 250)` and with the length of some global length variable.

In the question it looks like you are supposed to replace the hard coded numbers (`(-250, 250)`) with `startx, starty` and also add a length parameter argument.

You should change you function signature to:

```
def square(length, startx, starty):
```

And then use those arguments instead in the function body.

You can [read here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) about functions in python.

---

**In addition**, you might want to add `mike.penup()` at the first line of the function, before going to `(startx, starty)`, so it wouldn't draw on the screen before starting to draw the square.